# How to solve cloud foundry deployment to Azure

Tags: azure, cloud-foundry

I encounter an error trying to deploy cloud foundry to azure. Below is the stack trace. Any ideas how to resolve it?

```
Deploying
---------

Director task 7
Deprecation: Ignoring cloud config. Manifest contains 'networks' section.

  Started preparing deployment > Preparing deployment. Done (00:00:01)

Error 100: Unable to render instance groups for deployment. Errors are:
   - Unable to render jobs for instance group 'cf_z1'. Errors are:
     - Unable to render templates for job 'cloud_controller_ng'. Errors are:
       - Error filling in template 'cloud_controller_api.yml.erb' (line 131: undefined method `empty?' for 123456:Fixnum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems BOSH is expecting a string for a value in your manifest and you have supplied a number. I'm not sure what version of cloudfoundry you are deploying but looking at [cloud_controller_api.yml.erb on line 131](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng/blob/a79b5588345bac8f1f2f7d05e06c05ef8666bb0c/bosh/jobs/cloud_controller_ng/templates/cloud_controller_api.yml.erb#L131), I think you should start by looking at the value for router.route_services_secret in your manifest.